# calling the same service multiple times using cfhttp post calls

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I am posting to an API that I am getting a error
"Routines cannot be declared more than once."

What I would like do is loop through a query and post transactions to this api.

Is there a way to create a cfhttp post to this API calls with out call a new page.
I could use a scheduling tool to call the page every 10 seconds - but I do not know of a server that I can do with.  I can not figure a way to set the ColdFusion schedule to run quicker then every 60 seconds.

Comment: Its hard to see what is going on. If you included your code, it would help a lot

Comment: Is using cron + wget or curl an option for you?

Comment: `Routines cannot be declared more than once.` means you have the same function more than once your code. You need to find that dupe and disable it (rename it, comment it out, or delete it).